# Wrong elements toggled when nested divs

Tags: jquery, html, click, nested, toggle

I've got a set of `div`s (systemHeaders) each having a header `h2` and a child `div`. Each child `div` (subSystems) has a header `h3` and a child `div` with some links. When I click on systemHeader I want to toggle only the subSystems `div`. When I click on subSystemHeader I want to toggle only reports `div`.

What is actually happening is that whatever I click on, toggles the subSystems `div`!

How can I make it work like it should and only toggle the first child `div` on each type of click?

```
<div class="pod">
    <li id='ThirdParty'>
        <div class='block'>
            <h1>ThirdParty</h1><img class='blockNoBorder' src='images/thirdparty.jpg' width="200"></img>
            <div class='systemHeader'>
                <h2><span>Bobs shop</span></h2>
                <div class='subSystems'>                    
                    <div class='subSystemHeader'>
                        <h3><span>&nbsp;Gifts</span></h3>
                        <div class='reports '>
                            <p class='reports i1'>
                                <a href='/Next.Whs.Web.MenuSystem/Default.aspx?id=470' title=''>Option 1</a></p>
                            <p class='reports i1'>
                                <a href='/Next.Whs.Web.MenuSystem/Default.aspx?id=471' title=''>Option 2</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='subSystemHeader'>
                        <h3><span>&nbsp;Directory</span></h3>
                        <div class='reports hidden'>
                            <p class='reports i1'>
                                <a href='/Next.Whs.Web.MenuSystem/Default.aspx?id=466' title=''>Option 3</a></p>
                            <p class='reports i1'>
                                <a href='/Next.Whs.Web.MenuSystem/Default.aspx?id=461' title=''>Option 4</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='systemHeader'>
                <h2><span>Robs shop</span></h2>
                <div class='subSystems'>
                    <div class='subSystemHeader'>
                        <h3><span>&nbsp;Gifts</span></h3>
                        <div class='reports '>
                            <p class='reports i1'>
                                <a href='/Next.Whs.Web.MenuSystem/Default.aspx?id=480' title=''>Option 5</a></p>
                            <p class='reports i1'>
                                <a href='/Next.Whs.Web.MenuSystem/Default.aspx?id=481' title=''>Option 6</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='subSystemHeader'>
                        <h3><span>&nbsp;Directory</span></h3>
                        <div class='reports hidden'>
                            <p class='reports i1'>
                                <a href='/Next.Whs.Web.MenuSystem/Default.aspx?id=486' title=''>Option 7</a></p>
                            <p class='reports i1'>
                                <a href='/Next.Whs.Web.MenuSystem/Default.aspx?id=481' title=''>Option 8</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>


            <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(
                function()
                {
                    jQuery('div.systemHeader').click(
                    function()
                    {
                        jQuery(this).find('div:first').slideToggle();
                    });
                },
                function()
                {
                    jQuery('div.subSystemHeader').click(
                    function()
                    {
                        jQuery(this).find('div:first').slideToggle();
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) will look for all children in all levels; you can either use [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) instead or use the below example:

```
$("div.subSystemHeader, div.subSystemHeader").click(function() {
   $("> div", this).slideToggle(...);
   return false;
});
```

I hope this help!

Comment: Thats almost there! Except that after it has toggled the Reports div it then also toggles the SubSystems div as well. The user can then click the SystemHeader to open it again and it looks spot on, but is there a way to do that in code??